# cannot resolve AutocompleteFilter.create

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-places-api, google-location-services

I am trying to use this code to filter autocomplete results from google places:

```
List<Integer> filters = new ArrayList<Integer>();   
filters.add(AutocompleteFilter.TYPE_FILTER_ADDRESS);
filters.add(AutocompleteFilter.TYPE_FILTER_CITIES);
mAutocompleteFilter = AutocompleteFilter.create(filters);
```

but it cannot resolve method AutocompleteFilter.create.

build.gradle:

```
compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.4.2"
compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:11.4.2"
compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.4.2"
compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:11.4.2"
```

Is it because of version 11.4.2? I don't want to downgrade. Is there any other alternative to use multiple integers in this AutocompleteFilter?

Answer (score 1):

There is no `create` method instead use `AutocompleteFilter.Builder`.

[`From Docs`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/places/AutocompleteFilter)

> Use **AutocompleteFilter.Builder** to create a new AutocompleteFilter.

```
mAutocompleteFilter = new AutocompleteFilter.Builder()
        .setTypeFilter(AutocompleteFilter.TYPE_FILTER_CITIES)
        .setTypeFilter(AutocompleteFilter.TYPE_FILTER_ADDRESS)
        .build();
```

Comment: AutocompleteFilter.Builder in its method accepts only one filter and I need the combination of  TYPE_FILTER_ADDRESS and TYPE_FILTER_CITIES.   :-( how is that possible then?

Comment: @mKosut please refresh the page and try the code or you can use `TYPE_FILTER_REGIONS` as well

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But code, you wrote only re-sets typeFilter from CITIES to ADDRESS. So it only accepts the last one, TYPE_FILTER_ADDRESS in this case. And TYPE_FILTER_REGIONS includes TYPE_COUNTRY. I need to exclude countries from my autocomplete.

Comment: @mKosut there is no other option to apply both filters , other way is you can create your own customize class to achieve your goal

Answer (score 0):

Seems, there are no possibilities to apply several filters via `AutocompleteFilter`, but you can use [`PlaceSearch`](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/search#PlaceSearchRequests) on each separate [`place type`](https://developers.google.com/places/supported_types#table1) instead of it:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location={LAT},{LON}&radius={RADIUS}&type={PLACE_TYPE, e.g. restaurant}&keyword=cruise&key={YOUR_API_KEY}
```